# Sqlcmd connect using active mfa authentication

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

Can anyone instruct how to connect to a remote SQL Server database using active MFA authentication? What command should be used to connect?

Comment: Have you checked the docs? [Configure multi-factor authentication for SQL Server Management Studio and Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-ssms-mfa-authentication-configure)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos nothing about sqlcmd ..

Comment: `sqlcmd` is just a client tool, it doesn't change how authentication works. You still haven't explained what you're doing though - MFA makes no sense for on-prem databases. Are you asking how to connect to *Azure SQL* when MFA is enabled? You should change the tags in that case, you're asking how to connect to SQL Server, not Azure SQL.  Did you check [sqlcmd's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos to be honest i have no idea where database is, i just knows how to connect to it from management studio - there i check: Authentication: Active Directory - Universal with MFA then username: something@something.pl

Answer (score 5):

If you are referring to Authenticating using AzureAD with MFA then you just need to use the -G switch without supplying a password. You will be prompted for the password and the MFA challenge.

```
$serverName = 'contososql.database.windows.net';
$userName="john.doe@contoso.com" # Azure AD username
$databaseName='contoso1'

Sqlcmd -S $serverName -d $databaseName -U $userName -G -I
```

Comment: This does not work on MacOS, any idea on this?

Comment: Did not work for me on Windows 10. The error message is  `you must use multi-factor authentication to access '022907d3-*******'`

Comment: You can also provide a password using -P instead of -I